# CSS will not read class names contained in quotes

Tags: html, css

My css sheet is linked from my HTML. Classes are only working in my HTML if I specify them with a space

```
<p class= task> </p>
```

If I specify them with a quote

```
<p class="task" >
```

weird characters show in the inspector. This is preventing me from using multiple classes. Example

```
<p class="task green"></p>
```

will only read the task element and not read the green element.

Comment: Hum. Invisible characters in your HTML ? Do your editor show all the characters ?

Comment: you mean there are weird characters replacing the `task` value ?

Comment: Does this also happen if you edit your HTML with a plane text editor? Something like notepad (windows) or TextEdit (Mac)

Comment: Is your file encoded with UTF8?

Comment: just to remove the probability of invisible characters can you copy your entire HTML to this [VI Editor](http://www.compileonline.com/online_vi_editor.php), check if any weird data & paste it back to your file if all are fine & try again.

Comment: "No encoding" ? There is some encoding, your file is made of bytes, not text.

Comment: Ended with UTF-8 Using textedit on mac

Comment: Tried VI editor, no invisible characters. Weird characters show up where the class name is written when I inspect the element on chrome.

Comment: Are you applying Class name using any code, or just writing it static ?

Comment: Consider posting a screenshot of what you're seeing, none of us will be able to reproduce this.

Comment: Also, are you sure the quotes you are typing are plain, straight quotes? Not smart, curly ones?

Comment: Do you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` set?

Answer (score 0):

this problem is only possible when all the styles are used in `task` so check that once and also check that is this class are in one .css file or are u declaring that class properly or not. just check that u will get your answer

Comment: I am unable to understand this answer. What do you mean by "all the styles are used in `task`"? Could you clarify? If you want the OP to check something, leave that as a comment, not an answer. By the way, in standard international English as used on SO we write out "you", capitalize the first word of sentences, and put a period (full stop) at the end of sentences. This is not an SMS conversation.